# Calculating arc length of an infinite(?) curve

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, arc-length

English is not my first language so please excuse me for possibly not expressing myself clearly.

I am a computer science student and I've just finished calculus this semester.

I was having fun with parametric curves and their lengths when I stumbled upon this one:

$$
x = x(t)= e^t\\y=y(t)=\cos(e^{-t})
$$
[graph picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXjyZ.png)

I wanted to find the arc length near zero so I got down to this integral:
$$
 \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{{(e^t)}^2 + ({e^{-t}})^2 \cdot \sin^2(e^{-t})} \,dt 
$$

Wolfram computes it to be about 1.79
That's what I don't understand. Doesn't the arc oscilate an infinite amount of times before it gets to zero? I know that the function doesn't have a limit when $t\rightarrow-\infty$, so I guess I can't integrate it? Or am I just overthinking everything?

Comment: See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=arc+length+cos%281%2Fx%29+from+e%5E0+to+e%5E1). You did not calculate the length over $0\le x\le 1$, but rather $0\le t\le 1\iff 1\le x\le e$. The arc length over $0\le x\le 1$, however, is infinite

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thanks! But how can I rigorously know that the length is infinite? Should I use improper integral then?

Comment: @akb32c let $\varphi :[a,b]\to \Bbb R^n$, if $\varphi \in C^1([a,b])$ and $||\varphi'(t)||\neq 0$, the the arc length is finite and $\ell (\varphi) =\int_a^b ||\varphi'(t)|| dt$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation does not compute the arc length of the part of the curve with $x \in (0, 1]$ but rather the length of the curve defined by the parameter range $t \in [0, 1]$, which corresponds to the part of the curve with $x \in [x(0), x(1)] = [e^0, e^1] = [1, e]$.

To compute the arc length of the part of the curve with $x \in (0, 1]$, we can integrate over $t \in (-\infty, 0]$, since $\lim_{t \to -\infty} x(t) = 0$ and $x(0) = 1$: Substituting $u = \frac{1}{x} = e^{-t}$ transforms the arc length integral to
$$ \int_1^\infty \sqrt{\frac{1}{u^2} + \sin^2 u} \,du,$$ but
$$\int_1^\infty \sqrt{\frac{1}{u^2} + \sin^2 u} \,du > \int_1^M |\sin u| \,du,$$ and the latter quantity goes to $\infty$ as $M \to \infty$, hence the arc length is infinite as expected.

Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve.